# Generate list of rsync errors -- after the fact

Tags: rsync, corruption

I'm in the process of salvaging what I can from an external hard drive. My Macbook can no longer read the disk at all, so I have the corrupted drive plugged into an old Linux notebook, and I'm copying everything over using `rsync` via ssh. It all went well and *most* of the files were copied over. But, when it finished, I saw a handful of errors, looking like this:

```
rsync: read errors mapping "/media/skifreak/kcMASTER/Photos/kc photos/INDIA MASTER/INDIA MASTER/Seltzer Delhi:Agra/IMG_2626.DNG": Input/output error (5)
ERROR: Photos/kc photos/INDIA MASTER/INDIA MASTER/Seltzer Delhi:Agra/IMG_2424.JPG failed verification -- update retained.
```

So, some of these files are broken, and that's fine. I have an older backup that I can use to recover these.

But, I didn't have the foresight to be putting all of these errors into a log. Is there a way I can scan through the drive to output a list of all corrupted files?

Answer (score 1):

You could always run the same `rsync` again, this time redirecting stderr into a log. This would have the possible added benefit of recovering some of the corrupt files successfully (often on a degrading HDD read errors will be intermittent, and repeated attempts to read a single area may recover data even after the first one fails).

Alternatively, you could issue something like `find /mnt/corrupted >~/corrupted_list` and then check for files that are missing in the rsync'd mirror.